# Phonegap File Transfer of picture fails on every other picture: Error code 3 with FileTransfer upload

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I answered this question myself since it took me a long time to find the solution for it and it wasn't documented very well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While trying to use [**FileTransfer()**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) to upload images from a **[phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com)** app on android to a remote server i kept getting an **error code 3** on every alternate file upload. 

It worked once but instantly when i tried again it would throw an error without even sending the file to the server.

**The code i am using for the file upload was :**

The key to making it work was to add a **header option.**

```
options.headers = {
        Connection: "close"
    }
    options.chunkedMode = false;
```

The complete code :

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();

                        options.fileKey="file";
                        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
                        options.chunkedMode = false;
                        *options.headers = {
                           Connection: "close"
                        };*

                        // setup parameters
                        var params = {};
                        params.fullpath =imageURI;
                        params.name = options.fileName;



                        var ft = new FileTransfer();

                        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI(url+'/account/profile-pics'), win, fail, options);


 function win(r) {
                  //file uploaded successfully
                }
            function fail(error) {


                alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
                alert("upload error source " + error.source);
                alert("upload error target " + error.target);
            }
```

Comment: This is Extremely frustrating that this is not better documented by phonegap.  Your solution worked for me, thanks.

Comment: I was getting this error (error code 3 ) because file size configured on php module on apache server was less than what I was posting as part of the request. Once i increased the limit, it was fixed for me.

Comment: Error code 3 also comes when internet is disconnected.

Comment: I'm getting this error after an initial success. One success and then never works again until page refresh. The above answer did not work for me using iOS.

Comment: In my case I had to add an Authorisation header since the server expects a token and it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 3 is a rather broad error; it basically means your server isn't coded correctly or you don't have an internet connection, and that results in a connection error.

Could mean:

1. You don't have a multipart plugin installed on the server. In PHP set "file_uploads = On" (in PHP.ini), in ExpressJS you need the Multer middleware plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), etc.
2. That the file upload is larger than what your server permits - which results in error of status code 413, with a message of "request entity is too large". To fix this on PHP you need to adjust the `upload_max_filesize` setting in php.ini, to fix this on ExpressJS you need to adjust the `limit` field for Multer, etc. Basically, increase the file upload size on the server. Most servers limit file upload sizes as a security measure. (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload)
3. That the `options.fileKey` value (i.e. `<input type="file" name="fileKey" />`) isn't the name your server expects - an example error message might be "unexpected field".
4. That the `content-type` field in the header does not have a value of `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary`. Logging the request header on the server, could be used to check if content-type is correctly set.

## Photo upload with File Transfer

@AugieGardner - Also in agreement that the Cordova File Transfer plugin isn't well documented for uploading photos taken with the Camera plugin.

Fortunately, I have a working example for iOS (and my guess is Android as well):
[cordova file transfer plugin not working in ios simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017152/cordova-file-transfer-plugin-not-working-in-ios-simulator/37906904#37906904)

## Photo upload without File Transfer

A simpler alternative (or fallback), would be to encode the image as Base64, and send it through a plain old AJAX POST request. Which includes the following advantages and disadvantages.

**Disadvantages of Base64 encoded images sent over AJAX**

1. You may need to increase the request limit size on your server, so you don't get 413 errors (i.e. "request entity too large").
2. Base64 images are about 37% larger than binary images, which most likely results in slower uploads.
3. May not be suitable for videos, or other file types.

**Advantages of Base64 encoded images sent over AJAX**

1. Smaller app size (and faster app download), because Cordova's *File Transfer plugin*, and possibly Cordova's *File plugin* won't add overhead to the app.
2. You don't have to fix *File Transfer plugin* errors, as you scale your app to new operating systems (i.e. iOS, Android, etc).
3. You may not need a multipart service (or middleware) on the server to upload images.