# Upload multiple files show error code : 3

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, file-upload

This question is same like asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275268/phonegap-file-transfer-of-picture-fails-on-every-other-picture-error-code-3-wit). I want to upload files from device to server, when uploading files ( **totally 8 files**) it `shows error code : 3` for some files( **first 5 files** ) and rest of the files( **last 3 files** ) uploaded successfully.

My code is like:

```
for(i = 0;i < skiArray.length;i++){
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = skiArray[i];
    options.mimeType = "application/pdf";
    options.headers = {
            Connection: "close"
        }
        options.chunkedMode = false;
    var params = {};
    params.filePath = "/example/samp/files/ski/pdf/";
    options.params = params;
    uploadFiles("/example/samp/files/ski/pdf/"+skiArray[i],FILE_UPLOAD_URL,options);

}


//upload files to server
function uploadFiles(filelocation,url,options){
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
           ft.upload(filelocation, url,function onFileTransferSuccess(response){
               alert("File upload Success");  
           }, dbErrorHandler, options);

}
```

**NOTE:** all files are in same location  and file size are nearly same(not more than 200 KB). Cordova version 3.3

Please help me to solve this error.

consloe error is like

05-08 13:02:54.204: E/FileTransfer(18180):

```
{"target":"http:\/\/192.168.1.4\/novema\/Novema_Apiupload.php","source":"\/example\/samp\/files\/ski\/pdf\/51308_1_SKI133R_pxsc8717.pdf","http_status":0,"code":3}
05-08 13:02:54.204: E/FileTransfer(18180): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
05-08 13:02:54.204: E/FileTransfer(18180):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport$FixedLengthOutputStream.write(HttpTransport.java:228)
```

Comment: Dear downvoter put the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Hi phonegap fileTransfer use HTTP multi-part POST request ,this error  is due to the connection error. error code : 3 means  **CONNECTION_ERR**

**Errorr codes**

1. FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR
2. FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR
3. FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR
4. FileTransferError.ABORT_ERR

so to solve this u need to try those files again,
first keep those fileUploadoptions [filelocation,url,options] in an array , and call Upload function for each item  and onSuccess remove that items from array and try to call upLoad  function again, inside upload function fetch one item from that array and process upload until array become empty.

Comment: thanks for your reply...above code also do the same like array..please can you change the code ..

Comment: Can you please share the code how to use array and remove when success.