# Error 3 File-Transfer Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I'm developing an application that will have to send images to an external server, downloaded and installed [the file-transfer](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer) , however it stopped working appearing error 3,  I am running xampp on my local network, below is my code, I took it from the plugin documentation

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Transfer Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Retrieve image file location from specified source
            navigator.camera.getPicture(
                uploadPhoto,
                function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
                {
                    quality         : 50,
                    destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType      : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                }
            );
        }

        function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

            var params = {};
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://192.168.0.105/upload/index.php"), win, fail, options);
        }

        function win(r) {
            console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        }

        function fail(error) {
            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
            console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
            console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
        }

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Upload File</p>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$new_image_name = strtolower($_FILES['file']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/".$new_image_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the header object to option once.
Solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275268/phonegap-file-transfer-of-picture-fails-on-every-other-picture-error-code-3-wit)

options.headers = {
        Connection: "close"
    }