# Error code 3 (Connection Error) when downloading multiple files in IONIC 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to **download** multiple files(images, pdf, video and audio) from server in ionic 3.

Using Ionic File Transfer Plugin :- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/

I am trying to download around 1k files from server. But when it starts, it works fine. But after some files are downloading, It shows an error with FileTransferError with Error Code 3 and rest of all the files will display the same image.

**CODE:-**

> // This function will get path of files(1k) from database and pass it to fileDownloadFromServer function .
>
> ```
> getDownloadFilePath() {
>         let that = this;
>             return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>                 that.database.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tableName').then((data) => {
>
>                     for (let i = 0, len = data.rows.length; i < len; i++) {
>                         that.fileDownloadFromServer(data.rows.item(i), data.rows.length).then((data) => { 
>                         });
>                     }
>                 }).catch(e => {
>                     console.log("here hjere");
>                     resolve("error");
>                     console.log(e);
>                 })
>             });
>     }
> ```
>
> // This function will actually download file from server using filetransfer object.
>
> ```
> fileDownloadFromServer(fileDownloadData, fileCount) {
>      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>             let that = this;
>             if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
>                 this.fileLocalpath = this.file.documentsDirectory;
>             } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
>                 this.fileLocalpath = this.file.dataDirectory;
>             }
>
>
>             that.options = {
>                 headers: {
>                     "Authorization": "Basic " + that.authData
>                 }
>             }
>
>             let fileTransferObj: FileTransferObject = that.fileTransfer.create();
>
>             let tmpFilePath = fileDownloadData.globalPath;
>             let tmpFileName = fileDownloadData.folderName;
>
>             let tmpRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000000);
>             let tmpSourceFilePath = encodeURI(downloadFilePath + tmpFilePath + '/' + tmpFileName);
>             let tmpTargetFilePath = that.fileLocalpath + tmpRandomNumber + '_' + tmpFileName.replace(/ /g, "_");
>
>
>             fileTransferObj.download(tmpSourceFilePath, tmpTargetFilePath, false, that.options).then((entry) => {
>                 console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
>             }, (error) => {
>                 console.log("Error for taget file = "+tmpTargetFilePath)
>                 console.log(error);
>             });
>         });
>     }
> ```

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275268/phonegap-file-transfer-of-picture-fails-on-every-other-picture-error-code-3-wit)

Comment: @jeffchef , I asked the question for downloading multiple files not for uploading. I have already tried to add option 'Connection' & 'chunkedMode', But it's not working.